# Object initialization with protocol and class name in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, initialization, protocols

In Ojective-C I wrote:

```
id <MyProtocol> object = [[NSClassFromString(@"aClassName") alloc] initWithObject:obj];
```

I would like to write this in Swift.

Is there to do the same or am I out of the language paradigm ?

edit :

Here's my context.
Somewhere I have :

```
- (instancetype)initWithObject:(NSArray *)array andClassName:(NSString *)className {
    self = [self initWithClassName:className];
    if(self) {
        _members    = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(id obj in array) {
            id <MyProtocol> object = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] initWithObject:obj];
            [_members addObject:object];
        };
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSClassFromString`? Swift is a strongly typed language. Why would you use a class by name? Please provide more info about your code.

Comment: I'm using a construction class that is not aware of the other classes of the application. I tell to this class : "ok now you'll be instantiate with this object and you'll contain this type of object. This like UITableView. You can register your cell only by giving the class.

Comment: Instead of giving it the name of the class, why aren't you giving it the class (`Class`) directly? That would be convertible to Swift easily. Or maybe it's a good use for generics? Without code, hard to judge.

Comment: By giving the class directly you mean a Class objet or directly MyClass ?

Comment: I edited my post if it can help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, you will need a generic class.

You class will have a generic type `<T : MyProtocol>`, `members` will be of type `[T]` and you can use `T` to create new instance.

You won't need to pass the `className` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to call that initializer on the class, you need to know that the class supports that initializer. So let's make the initializer required by the `MyProtocol` protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  init(object: AnyObject)
}
```

And then you can just do `NSClassFromString`, then cast the result to `MyProtocol.Type` (to assert that the class is a subtype of `MyProtocol`), which allows you to use the initializer you want:

```
let object = (NSClassFromString(className) as! MyProtocol.Type)(object: obj)
```